# objective-c using blocks with recursion

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

I am coding an iphone app. And when I used blocks with recursion in Objective-C,
 I got a warning message of

> Capturing addImageToUploadEntity strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle.

I created a block called `addImageToUploadEntity` is used to call an async function `[self.submissionEntity addImageData: toImageAlbumType: finish^{}]` one by one. When it hits the base `case (index <= 0)`, it reload the table View and return.

```
    __block void (^addImageToUploadEntity)(NSUInteger) = ^(NSUInteger index){
        if (index <= 0)
        {
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            return;
        }

        [self.submissionEntity addImageData:[imagesPathArray objectAtIndex:index] toImageAlbumType:_currentOperatingImageAlbumType finish:^{
            // recursively call the block with index+1
            addImageToUploadEntity(index-1);
        }];
    };
    addImageToUploadEntity(5);
```

After I have researched a bit, some suggested to call the function `addImageToUploadEntity()` with weak type inside the block. So I rewrote this part and tried. Then, I got an error of 'bad access'.

What should I do in order to improve the code?
And with this block, does it have any memory leak risk?

```
    __block void (^addImageToUploadEntity)(NSUInteger);
    void (^__block __weak weakaddImageToUploadEntity)(NSUInteger);

    weakaddImageToUploadEntity = addImageToUploadEntity = ^(NSUInteger index){
        if (index <= 0)
        {
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            return;
        }

        [self.submissionEntity addImageData:[imagesPathArray objectAtIndex:index] toImageAlbumType:_currentOperatingImageAlbumType finish:^{
            // recursively call the block with index+1
            weakaddImageToUploadEntity(index+1);
        }];
    };
    addImageToUploadEntity(5);
```

Comment: @Bhavin It is no improvement whatsoever if you wrap misspelt words into code blocks. Please do not format the names of programming languages as code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The asynchronous completion handler for `addImageData:toImageAlbumType:finish:`  needs to capture a strong reference to your block.  Convert the weak reference back into a strong reference, and use the strong reference inside of the asynchronous completion handler:

```
typedef void (^AddImageBlock)(NSUInteger);

__block __weak AddImageBlock weakAddImage = nil;

AddImageBlock addImage = ^(NSUInteger index) {
    if (index <= 0)
    {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        return;
    }

    AddImageBlock strongAddImage = weakAddImage;
    [self.submissionEntity addImageData:[imagesPathArray objectAtIndex:index] toImageAlbumType:_currentOperatingImageAlbumType finish:^{
        // recursively call the block with index+1
        strongAddImage(index+1);
    }];
};

weakAddImage = addImage;
addImage(5);
```

The AddImageBlock will kept alive until the last asynchronous method handler is executed and released.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, hope it will be help you -

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

__block void (^addImageToUploadEntity)(NSUInteger) = ^(NSUInteger index){
        if (index <= 0)
        {
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            return;
        }

        [self.submissionEntity addImageData:[imagesPathArray objectAtIndex:index] toImageAlbumType:_currentOperatingImageAlbumType finish:^{
            // recursively call the block with index+1
            //addImageToUploadEntity(index-1);

            [weakSelf addImageToUploadEntity:index-1];
        }];
    };
    addImageToUploadEntity(5);
```